# Should I use a separate table for repetitive values (varchar)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

I have a table in which 3 rows of data are added per second and in which I intend to keep around 30M rows. (Older data will be removed).

I need to add a column: varchar(1000). I can't tell in advance what it's content will be but I do know it will be very repetitive : thousands to millions of rows will have the same value. It is usually around 200 characters long.

Since data is being added using a Stored Procedure I see two option

1. Add a column varchar(1000)
2. Create a table (int id,varchar(1000) value)
   Within the StoredProcedure, look if the value exist in that other table or create it
   I would expect this other table to have a maximum of 100 value at all time.

I know some of the tradeoff between these two options but I have difficulty making up my mind on the question.

Option 1 is heavier but I get faster inserts. Requires less joins hence query are simpler.
Option 2 is lighter insert take longers but query have the potential to be faster. I think I'm closer to normal form but then I also have a table with a single meaningful column.

From the information I gave you, which option seems better? (You can also come up with another option).

Comment: Will there be a lot of NULL values in this new column? Will you need to search the large table based on contents of this column?   Also, how many characters is the table already?

Comment: Add which version of Microsoft SQL (assumed by tSQL tag) are you using?

Comment: I expect around 20% of NULL values. I might need to do some search based on the content of this column but most of the time scope will have been reduced to around 100k row by an indexed column. Around 200characters per entry.

Comment: Based on what you've described, I would suggest the second approach.  In general, that will allow more data to be placed into the memory buffer each time you pull a record from the first table.  I would also be concerned with the maximum table size allowed by SQL.

Comment: The amount of rows being kept is pretty much driven by the maximum table size of SQL Express, of course option 2 would allow for a bit more rows but lets not consider it for the moment.

Comment: Are the values for the repetetive column equal by coincidence or is there a separate entity hidden in the data? Also: will they ever change after the insert?

Comment: The values are somewhat related : I might want to count on this column. Values will never change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also investigate [page compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464.aspx), perhaps you can do the simple thing and still get a a small(ish) table. Although, if you say is SQL Express, you won't be able to use it as is an Enterprise Edition requirement.

I have used repeatedly in my projects your second approach. Every insert would have to go through a stored procedure that gets the lookup value id, or inserts a new one if not found and returns the id. Specially for such large columns like your seems to be, with plenty of rows yet so few distinct values, the saving in space should trump the additional overhead of the foreign key and lookup cost in query joins. See also [Disk is Cheap... That's not the point!](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx).

Comment: Alltough this specific database is running an express edition we have a full version deployed in another context and page compression could be useful. Thanks for the pointer. From all the comments and this answer I'm getting the following: Stick to normal form at all time unless you have a specific reason to denormalize.